# Bash get fields with cut

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have these string:

```
./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.sh
./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.sh.t
./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.cpp
./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.g.j
./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.l.am.c
```

I have a lot of paths of files, that are beginning with `.`. I want to get the whole line except the `.` at the beginning. As you can see the delimiter is `.`. I've tried it with cut:

```
for path in "${path[*]}"; do PathToCheck=(`$path | cut -d"." -f1,-f2`)
```

This is not working really well because I don't know how many dots I'll have in the file name, is there any way to say that I want from field 1 till field 'n' or till the end of the string , I want to be able use `cut` and `sed` or `awk` as it's much more efficient when I'm processing thousands of paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get rid only of the dot at the beginning, use this:

`echo "./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.sh" | cut -c2-`

Result:
`/ABC/ABC/SRC/test.sh`

This will print everything except the first character of each line (no matter if it is dot or not).

**EDIT**:

Bash-only version:

```
string="./ABC/ABC/SRC/test.sh"
echo ${string#.}
```

This will strip dot from the beginning of `$string` variable. If there is no dot, it won't do anything.

Comment: @user3502786 I have added bash-only version without any external command, which will work also if some files won't have the dot at the beginning.